# what does these exceptions mean?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does this mfc appliction “First-chance exception” exception mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722780/what-does-this-mfc-appliction-first-chance-exception-exception-mean)

First-chance exception at 0x00939044 in Media.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000048.

Unhandled exception at 0x77b515de (ntdll.dll) in Media.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000048