# what does “First-chance exception ” mean in vc++ mfc application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does this mfc appliction “First-chance exception” exception mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722780/what-does-this-mfc-appliction-first-chance-exception-exception-mean)

First-chance exception at 0x75fdb9bc (KernelBase.dll) in Media.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.